# Shift+E to change units in top does not work

Tags: linux, top, sizing

I want to toggle the sizes top shows.
top -M does work, but when I try to toggle the sizes after top has opened using shift+E (as some suggested) it does not work.
Why is that and what is the alternative?
I will appriciate any help!

Comment: What distro / version of top are you using? In the version i have 'E' works, this is my package info:   procps-ng version 3.3.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be version dependent. For example My Fedora 24 with procps-ng version 3.3.10 doesn't have the -M command line argument but it does have <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>. My CentOS 6.8 with procps version 3.2.8 has the -M command line argument but it doesn't have <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>. A quick scan of the man page on C6.8 doesn't reveal any way to do what you want if <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> isn't available.